# Simple text editor with the ability to change font

Tags: java, swing

Im currently working on simply text editor. But im stuck. 
I divided my program into three differend classes:

- Notepad - main class responsible for creating gui.
- ButtonPanel - creating button, action listeners, jcomboboxes etc.
- WriteArea - creating area where we can write.

And to the point, in ButtonPanel class im creating JComboBox, where you can choose font type and listening to the event, and when the event occurs, assing 'currentFont' value from JComboBox. But I cant send updated 'currenFont' to the WriteArea, and my question is how to refresh this class to get currentFont variable.

BTW. 
IF you see another mistakes or just bad coding stuff, dont be shy and write that :D

```
package SimpleNotepad;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Notepad extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Notepad();
            }
        });
    }

    public Notepad(){
        ButtonPanel buttonPanel = new ButtonPanel();
        WriteArea writeArea = new WriteArea(buttonPanel);

        //setSize(800, 600);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(writeArea);
        setJMenuBar(buttonPanel.menuBar);
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

and ButtonPanel.java

```
package SimpleNotepad;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class ButtonPanel extends JPanel {

    JMenuBar menuBar;
    private String currentFont = "Arial";
    private String currentStyle;
    private int currentSize;

    private String[] fontTypes = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getAvailableFontFamilyNames();
    private String[] fontStyles = {"Plain", "Bold", "Italic"};
    private Integer[] fontSizes = {9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14};

    public ButtonPanel(){
        menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu menu = new JMenu("File");
        menuBar.add(menu);
        JMenuItem menuOpen = new JMenuItem("Open");
        JMenuItem menuZapisz = new JMenuItem("Save");
        menu.add(menuOpen);
        menu.add(menuZapisz);

        Box theBox = Box.createHorizontalBox();

        JComboBox fontList = new JComboBox(fontTypes);
        JComboBox fontStyle = new JComboBox(fontStyles);
        JComboBox fontSize = new JComboBox(fontSizes);

        fontList.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JComboBox comboBox = (JComboBox) e.getSource();
                currentFont = (String)comboBox.getSelectedItem();
                System.out.println(currentFont);
            }
        });

        JButton fontColor = new JButton("Font Color");
        JButton backgroundColor = new JButton("Background Color");

        theBox.add(fontList);
        theBox.add(fontStyle);
        theBox.add(fontSize);
        theBox.add(fontColor);
        theBox.add(backgroundColor);
        add(theBox);

    }

    public String getCurrentFont() {
        System.out.println(currentFont);
        return currentFont;
    }

}
```

WriteArea.java

```
package SimpleNotepad;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class WriteArea extends JPanel {

    JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(20, 50);
    private ButtonPanel buttonPanel;

    public WriteArea(ButtonPanel buttonPanel){

        this.buttonPanel = buttonPanel;
        String fontName = buttonPanel.getCurrentFont();
        Font font = new Font(fontName, Font.ITALIC, 12);


        textArea.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        textArea.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        textArea.setFont(font);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

        add(scrollPane);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this solution is very elegant, but it works for me: Let the `WriteArea` class extend `KeyListener` and add the `textArea` to this KeyListener. You can then set the font in the keyPressed method. This will check the selcted font every time a key is pressed and the `WriteArea` is focused (it needs to be focused if you want to type something into it). Here the parts that have changed:

```
public class WriteArea extends JPanel implements KeyListener{
//...
     textArea.addKeyListener(this);
//...
}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {
    if (this.getFont().getFontName() != buttonPanel.getCurrentFont()) {
    textArea.setFont(new Font(buttonPanel.getCurrentFont(), Font.ITALIC, 12));
    }
}
```

Note: Curently only works for the font family, but you should be able to extend this to work with size and style aswell. Also your code appears to be very clean to me, I didn't know that you could cast an `ActionEvent` the way you did.